# Type checking in C++

Tags: c++, casting, typechecking

In C++, I want to know whether the actual type of the object is from the same class, not the same class or a derived one.  This is similar to the following C# code:

```
Class Base
{
}

Class Child:Base
{
}

Base childObject = new Child();

If (childObject.GetType() == typeof(Child))
{
 // do some code
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `childObject`? There's no general way to do this in C++ because, at runtime, the concept of a type does not exist.

Comment: Though you said nothing about what childObject.GetType() is, nevertheless this code is terrible, because it branches on type comparison. That's what OOP is supposed to eliminate.

Comment: @Gene: The question can only be understood if you come from C# and know what object.GetType() does.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's not a good thing to do that in any object oriented language, including languages (like C#) which run on the CLR.

Comment: @Billy: I'm not saying that it's a great idea- I also think it's stupid. However, fundamentally, you can't deal with the question if you don't understand the functionality he's looking to replace.

Comment: :), thank you all, but it's not my code and I'm just trying to solve a problem quickly and I'm not interested to know or solve the logic.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are two ways that you can do this.  First, you can use the `typeid` operator, which returns a `type_info` structure containing information about the type of the object.  For example:

```
Base* ptr = /* ... */
if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(DerivedType)) {
    /* ... ptr points to a DerivedType ... */
}
```

Notice that you have to use `typeid(*ptr)` and not `typeid(ptr)` here.  If you use `typeid(ptr)`, then you'll get back a `type_info` object for `Base*`, since the pointer has type `Base*` regardless of what it points at.

An important point to note is that this will check if what `ptr` points at is *exactly* a `DerivedType`.  If `ptr` is pointing at an object of a type derived from `DerivedType` (maybe an `EvenMoreDerivedType`), this code will not work correctly.

An alternative way of checking whether you are pointing at an object of some type that is a bit more robust is to use the `dynamic_cast` operator.  `dynamic_cast` performs a checked typecast at runtime that will yield a valid pointer if the cast succeeds and `nullptr` otherwise.  For example:

```
Base* ptr = /* ... */;
auto* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(ptr);
if (derived) {
    /* ... points to a DerivedType ... */
}
```

This has the added advantage that if `ptr` points at something like an `EvenMoreDerivedType`, the cast will still succeed because `EvenMoreDerivedType` inherits from `DerivedType`.

As a final thought, you sometimes see code like this:

```
Base* ptr = /* ... */
if (auto* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(ptr)) {
     /* ... points to a DerivedType ... */
}
```

This locally-scopes the `derived` pointer to the body of the `if` statement and uses the fact that nonzero values evaluate to `true` in C++.  I personally find this easier to read and less error-prone, but by all means go with what's easiest for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He wants to know if the object is a Base, not if it's a derived class.

Comment: Ah... I got confused by his sample code, which was checking if the pointer was pointing at a child type.  A valid point.

Answer (score 12):

While DeadMG's answer is correct (I've used typeid many times), I thought I'd throw this out there for posterity.  The "right" way to do this, from an Object-Oriented view is:

```
Class Base
{
    virtual void something() {
        // probably a no-op, but maybe some default stuff
    }
}

Class Child : public Base
{
    virtual void something() {
        // do your child-specific code here
    }
}

Base* childObject = new Child();
childObject->something();  // does the right thing
```

Comment: I second this answer. DeadMG's answer though correct may not be a good programming practice .. !

Comment: This works well when you want to do something internal to the object. On the other hand, when you want to process objects depending on their types, it becomes complicated and inconvenient (with all those double dispatches and visitors)

Comment: @7vies, true, but most commonly, this virtual method approach will work best, and be easiest to maintain.  There are times when dynamic_cast or typeid is the right approach, but those are rarer occasions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but as I said, it's not my code, and I'm just solving a problem quickly without changing anything.

Comment: @Homam, you can still do it with OO by creating your own wrapper classes.  But it's usually not worth it at that point, and typeid/dynamic_cast becomes the more reasonable option.  Especially if you're just looking for a quick fix.

Comment: This is still not great programming practice. Container objects should not have to contain logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use typeid().

```
if (typeid(childObject) == typeid(ChildType)) {
}
```

If this returns true, then you know it's the child class.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you compile with runtime type identification (RTTI) enabled too.

Comment: Note that this **only works** if the item being compared has a vtbl.

Comment: @Billy: That's true- but who doesn't give their base classes virtual destructors? Virtual functions are practically the point of inheritance. It's not unreasonable to expect it.

Comment: @Richard Cook: If you're using a C++ compiler it will have RTTI support. Turning RTTI off would put it in non conforming mode and in a general question about C++ there's no real reason to list C++ features that shouldn't be switched off.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think it's worth making it explicit. I think that I generally write about the same number of classes that don't have virtual destructors as do. Of course, I don't expect to be doing run time type checking on these classes.

Comment: @DeadMG: STL containers won't agree with you

Comment: @7vies: You don't inherit from STL containers. Unless you're insane. Or so experienced in the language, that you will already know about typeid() and the virtual function restriction. @Charles: I also rarely give my classes virtual destructors- but I always do if I plan on inheriting from them.

Comment: @DeadMG: of course I don't - I just misunderstood what is not going to work without a vtbl. Now I got it, and indeed it doesn't make sense to have a dynamically typed class without a virtual destructor.