# How to check if a struct has a certain variable?

Tags: c++, struct, void-pointers

So I have the following two structs. Let's say I have a void pointer that, depending on the situation, will point to either bag or apple. How do I check which struct type it is pointing to so I can dereference it?

```
struct product
{
        int price;
        string name;
};

struct fruit : product
{
        int weight;
};

product bag;
fruit apple;
```

edit: so this is just the simplified version of code i'm working with at my new job. I need to check for a certain variable, but like the weight variable in fruit, sometimes it is passed with a void pointer and sometimes it isn't. There's a lot of code already so changing it from void pointers would be too much. I need to check if the weight variable exists, and then do something based on what value is in it.

Comment: Use `typeid` or better meta programming with templates.

Comment: This sounds like bad design. You should most likely not switch on types in the first place.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, in fact, it is a very standard OOP design, it's just that OP is not wording it properly and suggesting incorrect technique.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `typeid()` function. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589292/4922156

Comment: `typeid()` won't work with `void*`

Comment: @WernerHenze - you can't use `typeid` on a `void*`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `void*` in C++. There is almost never a case when it is valid to use `void*` as a real data object in client code.

In your case, instead of `void*`, you need to use `product*`, and declare destructor of `product*` virtual. This way you will be able to test for the actual object using `dynamic_cast`.

Even a better option is to carefully design your classes, introduce the proper virtual functions and make sure you **never** need to know the actual type of the object. But this is a topic of a separate question.

Comment: `void*` is useful when you don't have control of the base class or when you don't want to bring overhead.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, please explain yourself.

Comment: `void*` is really useful when you want to hold a collection of unrelated types. Sometime you don't have control over the which base class the object you got have. You could certainly make a wrapper over the unrelated type, but RTTI and polymorphism adds overhead you don't have with `void*`. You have to use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: But I must agree with you that for this particular case, your solution is the best.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, this is the worst possible example of using `void*`.

Comment: `boost::any` would make more sense than `void*`. Still, inheritance is better than that.

Comment: `void*` are a tool just like polymorphism. If you don't find any good use case then don't use the tool. But if you know when and how to use it, you can make thing even better than you did without this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the comments (`void*` is entrenched in existing API's), the workaround would be a two-step cast. First, `static_cast<product*>` your `void*` pointer. Next, `dynamic_cast` that `product*` to `fruit*`.

You will need to add a virtual method to `product` as the `dynamic_cast` otherwise won't work.

Answer (score 0):

With only void pointer you can't. Void pointers strip all type information from the variable. You must use something like `std::type_index` if you must know the type at runtime.